# How to search for text in iframe and get its element?

Tags: jquery

How to search for some text in iframe and upon match get its element or append css class to it.

i have tried with :

```
$('#my_iframe').contents().find().text('my text');
```

but it is not working also i have read some articles with **:contains** but am not sure how to make it working for iframe.

######### Edited

Even tried this but it gives me "Undefined"

```
alert($('#my_iframe:contains("'+data+'")').first().tagName);
```

**Note :**
*Do not tell me how to use find method of Jquery, just answer my question of how to search for specific text and get its element.*

Answer (score 1):

use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)..it selects all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('#my_iframe:contains("I am a simple string")')
```

**Update**

if you are tyring to get a tagName thn try this..

```
alert($('#my_iframe:contains("'+data+'")').first().prop("tagName"));
```

**note**  that tag names are, by convention, returned CAPITALIZED,

Comment: i tried to do this alert($('#my_iframe:contains("'+data+'")').first().tagName); but it alerts "undefined"

Comment: `alert($('#my_iframe:contains("'+data+'")')); ` are u getting and obj alert if u do this??

Comment: I am getting this "[object Object]"

Comment: ya that means it is working... can u tell me what are you trying to do with the first and tagName ??

Comment: As you said, "it selects all elements that contain the specified text". So I wanted to get the first element

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22052/discussion-between-atif-and-bipen)

Comment: it is still giving me "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for the correct usage of `find`.

You could wrap the text into a span or div with an id, then manipulate it. This is an example for adding a `cssClass` to an element with id of `container`.

> ('#my_iframe').contents().find('#container').addClass('cssClass');

Comment: i do not know the id or class of the element containing the text

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_iframe").contents().find("#myContent");
```

Comment: I don't have the id or class of element containing the text

Comment: if possible can you give id or class to element.

Comment: the text i am searching for is coming from DataBase so how can i do that for dynamic data

Comment: but you are getting coming text in some element like Div, ok give id of div like <Div id="div1"> and get exact element in this div like find("#div1 label") or div or something element.

Answer (score 0):

Atif you can find your text in an iframe body this way:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('h2').text();
```

you can find it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vjWaH/

Comment: i know i can do it if have the element name , id or class but i have just the string to search.